# HTML offline idle game

Tags: html

Is there a way to find the time you leave the site, and the time you reenter the site to get rewards for the offline idle part? Or is there just a way to find the minutes elapsed not on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setinterval like this:

```
<div id="seconds"></div>
<script>
    let i = 0
 setInterval(
function(){

    var seconds=document.getElementById("seconds");
    var xhttp;
       xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState != 4 || this.status != 200) {
        i++;
        seconds.innerHTML=i;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://yourdomain.com/", true); //to avoid cors policy 
    xhttp.send();
}
, 1000);
</script>
```

interval every 1s if client offline i++